# passing data json using django templates to the front (html)

Tags: html, json, django

I have a problem to send json data using django templates to the front (html).

This is the python code:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))    
def tasks_list_all(request):
    i = inspect()
    tasks_dic=i.registered_tasks()
    for cle in tasks_dic.keys():
        key=cle
    tasks_old_v=tasks_dic.get(key)
    tasks_new_v=[]
    for tasks in tasks_old_v:
        new_tasks=tasks.replace('infra_mngt.tasks.','') 
        tasks_new_v.append(new_tasks)
    add_new=tasks_new_v[-1].replace('provisionning.celery.','')
    tasks_new_v[-1]=add_new
    tasks_new_v_new=json.dumps(tasks_new_v)
    print "json.dumps(tasks_new_v)",tasks_new_v_new
    #~ return render(request, os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'infra_mngt', 'templates', 'tasks_all.html'), context={'list':tasks_new_v})
    #~ return render(request, os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'infra_mngt', 'templates', 'tasks_all.html'),{'list':tasks_new_v})
    return render(request, os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'infra_mngt', 'templates', 'tasks_all.html'),{'list':tasks_new_v_new})
```

this is the code of the front (tasks_all.html):

```
<h1>Dynamic list tasks</h1>
{% for list in tasks_new_v_new %}
   {{ list }}
{% endfor %}
```

But after execution, I don't get any elements of the list that I need, just the display of this html code:

```
<h1>Dynamic list tasks</h1>
```

Comment: For starters the key to use in your template is `list` not `tasks_new_v_new`. Change `{'list':tasks_new_v_new}` to `{'tasks_new_v_new': tasks_new_v_new}` if you want to use that as your key

Answer (score 1):

you're passing the wrong context to the template (or you're using the wrong variable in the template)

try something like (in the view):

```
return render(request, your_template, {"tasks": tasks_new_v_new})
```

in the template:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
  {{ task }}
{% endfor %}
```

notice I'm passing a variable called `tasks` to the template and in the template I'm looping that variable.

Hope this helps